# Select Column name of min value

Tags: sql-server

I have something i can't quite figure out, say you have table

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Test') IS NOT NULL drop table #Test
create table #Test (ID int, Value1 int, Value2 int, Value3 int, Value4 int, Value5 int)

insert into #Test values
(1, 1, 4, 6, 7, 3),
(2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5),
(3, 5, 2, 4, 2, 1),
(4, 0, 1, 1, 7, 2)
```

So from this table, I wish to select ID, name of column with Min value and name of Column with Max value, ignoring columns with value of 0

So result would be ...

```
ID  MinValue    MaxValue
 1   Value1      Value4
 2   Value3      Value5
 3   Value5      Value1
 4   Value2      Value4
```

How could I acomplish this, with sys tables? cross apply? Idea is not to go with case, as I am not sure all the time how many columns I will have (And I understand it's bad structure of table when I have to do something like this)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing column names dynamically to UNPIVOT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/48393/5203)

Comment: @GSerg But I don't want to unpivot anything, I have a problem figuring out which column has lowest and highest value without using case, after that I can make temp table with column names using tempdb.sys.columns and join to get column name

Comment: Why don't you want to unpivot? That way you can get the data into rows and use min / max

Comment: Which would be a more complicated version of using `unpivot`. For that fixed set of columns you would use `select distinct ID, first_value(column_name) over(partition by ID order by v), first_value(column_name) over(partition by ID order by v desc)
from #Test unpivot (v for column_name in ([Value1], [Value2], [Value3], [Value4], [Value5])) upvt
where v <> 0`. For dynamic set of columns use the link.

Comment: That actually is a beautiful and simple way ... thank you @GSerg